# Sample mean converges almost surely

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Given an arbitrary sequence of random variables $X_n$ such that $X_n$ converges to $0$ almost surely, how do I show that $S_n/n$ converges to $0$ almost surely?

I'm already suspicious of the result: consider the harmonic series where the terms goes to zero but the sum doesn't converge.

As a follow-up, if $X_n$ converges to zero in $L_p$, how do we show that the sample mean also converges to zero in $L_p$?

Comment: Is there an independence assumption or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is Cesaro, twice. Recall that, for every deterministic sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_n\to0$, one has $\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^nx_k\to0$.

- Applying this to $x_n=X_n(\omega)$ for almost every $\omega$ yields the first result.
- Since $\left\|\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^nX_k\right\|_{L^p}=\frac1n\left\|\sum\limits_{k=1}^nX_k\right\|_{L^p}\leqslant\frac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\left\|X_k\right\|_{L^p}$, applying this to $x_n=\|X_n\|_{L^p}$ yields the second result.

Independence is neither needed nor relevant.